# jquery. how to get each siblings height?

Tags: jquery, height, siblings

I think this is very easy question for someone who is more experienced in Jquery.

for example we have  simple html page with a few divs, and 3 of them have the same css class 'sidebar'

Each of this 'sidebar' divs have different content and different height.

I need to compare this divs height and find the longest one.

I know how to realize comparing, but I do not know how in Jquery I can take each of this divs

to store their value in vairable or array.

Comment: Are you specifying height of the div in sidebar class or is it explicitly given?

Comment: no, I do not specify it in class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$.each($('.sidebar'), function() {
    var height = $(this).height();
});
```

Comment: thank you! learning jquery, but sometimes it is difficult to do simple things, because I do not know all events and operators.

Comment: You're welcome. When in doubt, use the jQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/

Comment: What's with using `jQuery.each` over plain old `.each()`? See my answer for links to the two.

Answer (score 13):

I'm not sure why the two answers posted so far are using [`jQuery.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) rather than just calling [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) directly, so here's what I would recommend:

```
$('#elementID').siblings().each(function ()
{
    var height = $(this).height();
});
```

To put each height into an array:

```
var heights = [];
$('#elementID').siblings().each(function ()
{
   heights.push($(this).height());
});
```

Or, just use [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/):

```
var heights = $('#elementID').siblings().map(function ()
{
   return $(this).height();
}).get();
```

Comment: I was trying `$(this).siblings.each(function()...` and nothing was happening. Duhhh... now that I saw your code I realized I was missing the parenthesis! siblings() This is obvious since it's a function. Lost 15 minutes debugging this. :)

Answer (score 0):

When I had to do the same thing, this is the code I used:

```
    var tabPanels = $("...");
    var maxHeight = 0;

    $.each(tabPanels, function() {
        var height = $(this).height();
        maxHeight = (height > maxHeight) ? height: maxHeight;
    });

    $.each(tabPanels, function() {
        $(this).css("height", maxHeight + "px");
    });
```